# How can I make the calculation code more structured and understandable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a code that performs calculations of parts of fuel injectors. There are two classes in which the basic calculations take place, they are called **LiquidJetInjector **and **GasJetInjector**, respectively.

The **Reynolds **class stores constants for calculations.

The **SimilarCalculations** class is a class in which the calculations required in both **LiquidJetInjector **and **GasJetInjector **take place.

In order for the code to work correctly, first we need to pass the basic values to the **SimilarCalculations **class, and then to the class whose calculations we are interested in.

```
import math
from enum import Enum


class SimilarCalculations:
    def __init__(self, diameter: float, length: float, mass_flow_rate: float, viscosity: float, density: float):
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.length = length
        self.mass_flow_rate = mass_flow_rate
        self.viscosity = viscosity
        self.density = density

    def injector_nozzle_area(self) -> float:
        return (math.pi * self.diameter ** 2) / 4

    def reynolds_number(self) -> float:
        return (4 * self.mass_flow_rate) / (math.pi * self.diameter * self.viscosity)

    def average_speed(self) -> float:
        return self.mass_flow_rate / (self.density * self.injector_nozzle_area())

    def relative_length_injector(self) -> float:
        return self.length / self.diameter


class Reynolds(Enum):
    LAMINAR = 2000
    TURBULENT = 10000


class LiquidJetInjector:
    def __init__(self, density_comb: float, sigma_fuel: float):
        self.calculations = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)

        self.density_comb = density_comb
        self.sigma_fuel = sigma_fuel

        self.reynolds_number = self.calculations.reynolds_number()
        self.injector_nozzle_area = self.calculations.injector_nozzle_area()
        self.average_speed = self.calculations.average_speed()

    def linear_hydraulic_resistance(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 64 / self.reynolds_number

        elif Reynolds.LAMINAR.value <= self.reynolds_number <= Reynolds.TURBULENT.value:
            return 0.3164 * self.reynolds_number ** (-0.25)

        else:
            return 0.031

    def injector_losses_inlet(self) -> float:
        if self.reynolds_number < Reynolds.LAMINAR.value:
            return 2.2 - 0.726 * math.exp(-74.5 * ((viscosity * length) / mass_flow_rate))
        else:
            return 1 + 2.65 * self.linear_hydraulic_resistance()

    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return 1 / (math.sqrt(self.injector_losses_inlet() + self.linear_hydraulic_resistance() *
                              (length / diameter)))

    def pressure_drop_injector(self) -> float:
        return mass_flow_rate ** 2 / (2 * density * self.injector_flow_coefficient() ** 2 * self.injector_nozzle_area **
                                      2)

    def weber_criterion(self) -> float:
        return (self.density_comb * self.average_speed ** 2 * diameter) / self.sigma_fuel

    def media_diameter_spray_droplets(self) -> float:
        return diameter * round(math.pow((27 * math.pi) / 4, 1 / 3.)) * self.weber_criterion() ** (-0.333)


class GasJetInjector:
    def __init__(self, combustion_pressure: float, pressure_drop_internal_circuit: float, gas_constant_gen_gas: float,
                 temperature_gen_gas: float, entropy_expansion_ratio: float):
        self.calculations = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)

        self.reynolds_number = self.calculations.reynolds_number()
        self.injector_nozzle_area = self.calculations.injector_nozzle_area()
        self.average_speed = self.calculations.average_speed()

        self.combustion_pressure = combustion_pressure
        self.pressure_drop_internal_circuit = pressure_drop_internal_circuit
        self.gas_constant_gen_gas = gas_constant_gen_gas
        self.temperature_gen_gas = temperature_gen_gas
        self.entropy_expansion_ratio = entropy_expansion_ratio

    def calculate_injector_pressure(self) -> float:
        return self.combustion_pressure + self.pressure_drop_internal_circuit

    def density_gen_gas(self) -> float:
        return self.calculate_injector_pressure() / (self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas)

    def injector_flow_coefficient(self) -> float:
        return (math.sqrt(1.23 ** 2 + (232 * length) / (self.reynolds_number * diameter))) / \
               ((116 * length) / (self.reynolds_number * diameter))

    def injector_nozzle_area_outlet(self) -> float:
        return mass_flow_rate / (self.injector_flow_coefficient() * density * (
                self.combustion_pressure / self.calculate_injector_pressure()) ** (1 / self.entropy_expansion_ratio) *
                                 math.sqrt(2 * (self.entropy_expansion_ratio / (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1)) *
                                           self.gas_constant_gen_gas * self.temperature_gen_gas * (1 - (
                                            self.combustion_pressure / self.calculate_injector_pressure()) ** (
                                            (self.entropy_expansion_ratio - 1) / self.entropy_expansion_ratio))))

    def checking_diameter_injector(self) -> float:
        return math.sqrt((4 * self.injector_nozzle_area_outlet()) / math.pi)
```

To test the values at the end of the code, I used this construction (it is temporary and will not be in the final version, but I will attach it to understand the work)

```
#
diameter = 0.0005
length = 0.002
mass_flow_rate = 0.00712
viscosity = 0.00116
density = 1315
#
density_comb = 0.1
sigma_fuel = 0.5
#
combustion_pressure = 14.58 * 10**6
pressure_drop_internal_circuit = 10**6
gas_constant_gen_gas = 260.5
temperature_gen_gas = 777.4
entropy_expansion_ratio = 1.23
#
calc = SimilarCalculations(diameter, length, mass_flow_rate, viscosity, density)
calc_2 = LiquidJetInjector(density_comb, sigma_fuel)
calc_3 = GasJetInjector(combustion_pressure, pressure_drop_internal_circuit, gas_constant_gen_gas, temperature_gen_gas, entropy_expansion_ratio)
#
print(calc_3.injector_nozzle_area_outlet())
print(calc_2.injector_flow_coefficient())
print(calc.injector_nozzle_area())
```

How can this code be improved and how can we create a common entry point for it to eliminate the alternate invocation of two classes?

Comment: Might be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of instancing `SimilarCalculations`, you could subclass it with `LiquidJetInjector` and `GasJetInjector`. You will still have 2 entry points but both of them will inherit the methods from `SimilarCalculations`. If you want to reduce entry points, you could use a factory pattern, but it seems like overkill just to homogenize 2 separate calls.

Comment: @OysterShucker can you give an example of such a template, I just haven't seen anything like it (the simplest example)